# QT-FastStart Windows how to run it?

Tags: qt-faststart

So I have a lot of mp4 files on my computer and I read that QT-FastStart is for moving the metadata from the end of the files to the beginning but how do I use or run it ?

Every time I drag and drop a file into qt-faststart, nothing seems to happen?

I downloaded the 64bit version from here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140206214912/http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/blog/?p=59

Do I need a batch file or something or a specific command line parameter to make it run?

Answer (score 6):

Note,   QT-FastStart is described here https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ffmpeg/qt-faststart.1.en.html

> qt-faststart is a utility that rearranges a Quicktime file such that
>   the moov atom is in front of the data, thus facilitating network
>   streaming.

It can be used (perhaps among other purposes), for making a sample file when demonstrating an issue. One can take a large file, fix it with QT-FastStart, then use dd to cut a sample. And the sample should play. Whereas if you did dd without doing that then it wouldn't or may not play.

See Neil's answer `qt-faststart infile.mp4 outfile.mp4`

However, QT-FastStart has now been integrated into ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i original.3gp -codec copy -movflags +faststart fixed.3gp
```

Answer (score 1):

List item

simple. in CMD prompt run qt-faststart infile.mp4 outfile.mp4